# Neaten Class Declaration when having repeating methods c#

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, game-development

Im creating a class that has all of my data in and can see it would quickly become messy.

I feel that there must be a way of making it neater rather than making a new method each time

for example. I have a character that out of the huge skill list each with different values for diffeent things, they just have 1h weapon and shield. I declare this by

```
Character character = new Character();
character.Skills.Add(Skill.OneHanded());
character.Skills.Add(Skill.Shield());
```

it also makes it fairly easy if they level up and learn a new skill as i can just do

```
character.Skills.Add(Skill.Polearm());
```

however currently my Skill class looks like a mess

```
public class Skill
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public static Skill OneHanded()
    {
        return new Skill
        {
            Test = "test"
        };
    }
    public static Skill TwoHanded()
    {
        return new Skill
        {
            Test = "test2"
        };
    }
    public static Skill Polearm()
    {
        return new Skill
        {
            Test = "test3"
        };
    }
    public static Skill Shield()
    {
        return new Skill
        {
            Test = "test4"
        };
    }
}
```

is there a way to simply this?

Comment: You might put this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you considerd making the skill ID's a Enumeration? Using strings as important values is usualyl not a good idea.

Comment: I hadnt, how would you do this?

I can do enum Skill { OneHanded,TwoHanded,Polearm,Shield}; then use Skill.OneHanded as before but that would just return its place in the enum. how would I declare data against it?

Comment: also @rory.ap thanks for the suggestion. I aparently have to wait 40mins before I can, but i shall put it over there too